# Iterative solver for matrix division

Tags: matlab

I have two huge matrices $A$ and $B$. I am trying to find some iterative solvers like `bcg` or `lsqr` in Matlab.

I mean if my matrix $A$ is sparse and $n\times n$ and $B$ is a column vector of size $n\times 1$, I can use `lsqr` and `bcg` to solve the equation $Ax=B$.

Now suppose I need to solve $XD=C$, so I need to calculate $CD^{-1}$ where both $C$ and $D$ are huge matrices. If I use matlab's `C/D` operation directly, it consumes lots of memory and crashes. Are there any iterative solvers for this operation instead of using the forward slash operator directly?

Comment: How big is a "huge" matrix?

Comment: Around 4 million by 4 million

Comment: If you can transpose easily, solve $D^TX^T=C^T$ by standard techniques.

Comment: But methods like lsqr, bcg require the matrix B in the equation Ax=B to be a column matrix of size nx1. In my case the B matrix will not be a column matrix.So what should I do

Comment: Have you tried writing a loop which solves each of the columns of `B` individually? For example `result = sparse(N,N); for i = 1:N; result(:,i) = A\B(:,i); end`.

Comment: To elaborate slightly on @ChrisTaylor 's comment, the matrix eqn $XD = C$ can be solved for one row of $X$ using one corresponding row of $C$ at a time.  There are iterative approximations for $D^{-1}$ but computationally expensive like $O(n^3)$ per iteration, and even if $D^{-1}$ were handed to us, computing $CD^{-1}$ is also $O(mn^2)$ where $m$ is number of rows in $C$ (equiv. in $X$).

Comment: @Chris. Yeah I can use that so that I can solve it for one column of X at a time. But If I have to iterate for thousand of times, it's gonna cost me a lot of time, many hours

Comment: @user34790 Have you tried block methods? See [these notes](http://www.mai.liu.se/~akbjo/hels08.pdf) p. 16 onwards for a description with multiple RHS vectors.

Comment: If you have the Control Systems toolbox, you might try the following:

`X = lyap(zeros(n),D,-C);`

Comment: What kind of special structure does $D^T$ have beyond sparsity?  Is it symmetric positive definite or anything like that?

Answer (score 2):

The function [GMRES](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gmres.html) offers the best speed, though I think [QMR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qmr.html) uses less memory.  Otherwise the lu function allows you to recompose the matrix into an upper and a lower matrix like so: 
    [L,U,P] = lu(A);
    x = U(L(P*b));
Where A*x = b

Comment: LU isn't *that* computationally feasible for huge problems...

Comment: Right, but I think it intersects CG at around N=8000, so it's alright for small problems.  Big ones I'd go with QMR or GMRES.

Answer (score 1):

Let's frame your problem as a Sylvester equation:

$$ AX+XD - C = 0$$

with $A = 0$. We can solve Sylvester equations using `lyap`.

As per my comment, the following will work:

```
n = length(D);
lyap(zeros(n),D,-C);
```

Example:

```
n = 4;
B = rand(n);
C = rand(n);
C*inv(B)-lyap(zeros(n),B,-C)

ans =

  1.0e-014 *

   -0.2220   -0.2220    0.1221    0.3997
   -0.0666   -0.1582   -0.0278   -0.0611
    0.0666    0.0555    0.0444    0.5107
    0.0222   -0.0222    0.1332    0.7883
```

This has the benefit of the fact that the code that ships with `lyap` calls directly into LAPACK routines that *should* be capable of calling the appropriate sparse solvers/etc.

Comment: This solution is inelegant, but it is probably the easiest to employ out of the box. I don't have the control systems toolbox installed on a machine that can handle matrices of your size, so I have no idea how practical it might be. No claims are made that this is the *best* solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: rewrite $XD = C$ as $D^T X^T = C^T$.  Now solve for $X^T$ column by column.

For example, to get the first column of $X^T$, you would solve $D^T x = c_1$,
where $c_1$ is the first column of $C^T$.

You will have to solve many systems of equations (one for each column of $X^T$),
but that seems unavoidable, and at least each system is tractable.

If you use a method that first factors $D^T$, then (after the expensive factorization step, which is a one time cost) each system can be solved relatively cheaply using this factorization.  (But I'm not sure if a factorization method is appropriate for your large problem.)